# Cannot set format for excel cells by openpyxl in python 3

Tags: format, openpyxl

I use openpyxl with python 3.9.7 to set format for the excell cells but it does not help (nothing happens) in my computer but in my friend's computer, it works well.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
import openpyxl
##wb_style = openpyxl.Workbook() 
#Loading the Workbook
wb_style = load_workbook('test_Excel.xlsx')
 
#Accessing Product Informaiton Sheet
sheet = wb_style.active
 
#Set background color of cell
cell_bg1 = sheet["B2"]
cell_bg1.fill = PatternFill(start_color="800000", end_color="800000",fill_type = "solid")
 
 
#Set background color of cell
cell_bg1 = sheet["B3"]
cell_bg1.fill = PatternFill(start_color="FF8040", end_color="FF8040",fill_type = "solid")
 
#Set background color of cell
cell_bg1 = sheet["B4"]
cell_bg1.fill = PatternFill(start_color="FF0000", end_color="FF0000",fill_type = "solid")
 
#Set background color of cell
cell_bg1 = sheet["B5"]
cell_bg1.fill = PatternFill(start_color="408080", end_color="408080",fill_type = "solid")
 
#Set background color of cell
cell_bg1 = sheet["B6"]
cell_bg1.fill = PatternFill(start_color="800080", end_color="800080",fill_type = "solid")
for rows in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=6, min_col=None):
   for cell in rows:
     cell.fill = PatternFill(start_color="80FF00", end_color="80FF00",fill_type = "solid")
for rows in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=12, min_col=None):
   for cell in rows:
       if not cell.row % 2:
           cell.fill = PatternFill(start_color="C0C0C0", end_color="C0C0C0",fill_type = "solid")
wb_style.save("test_Excel.xlsx")
```

I am trying to install the new version 3.10.12 but it does not work also.

Comment: `"I am trying to install the new version 3.10.12 but it does not work also."` of Python? That would be a question not related to this post and should be raised as separate post and include details of the issue, i.e. what you have tried and what response(s) you get.

Comment: Your code suggest that  there is only filled cells in column A and column B and all other columns are empty. Still your still seems to be wasteful. It seems the `iter_rows` loops could do what the individual fills on B2,B3,B4,B5 & B6 are doing. As for why it works on one and not the other what are the differences, OS, Excel versions? You may need to check the xml of the files produced.